# laravel inertia react setup issue

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-blade, inertiajs

i am trying to setup react into an existing laravel 9 project with inertia.i followed 2 or 3 blogs on how to do the setup. but still getting nothing.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { createInertiaApp } from "@inertiajs/inertia-react";
import { InertiaProgress } from "@inertiajs/progress";
import { resolvePageComponent } from "laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers";

export default createInertiaApp({
    resolve: (name) =>
        resolvePageComponent(
            `./Pages/${name}.jsx`,
            import.meta.glob("./Pages/**/*.jsx")
        ),
    setup({ el, App, props }) {
        return render(<App {...props} />, el);
    },
});

// you can specify any color of choice
InertiaProgress.init({ color: "#4B5563" });
```

this is the code for setting up react in app.blade.php but after ruiing npm run dev i am getting following error.
https://i.imgur.com/DZdYFna.png

Comment: provide your vite.config.js, so that we can see that react and intertia is properly set.